# SCNText Alignment not working in iOS

Tags: swift, ios8, scenekit

I tried right alignment, but it's still left aligned.

```
let txt = SCNText(string: "TEST", extrusionDepth: 10) 
txt.chamferRadius = 5 //0<chamfer<extrusion depth
txt.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents  = UIColor.whiteColor() 
txt.containerFrame = CGRectMake(-200, -150, 400, 200) //on iPad Air Sim in Landscape
txt.wrapped = true
txt.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentRight
```

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like alignment is working -- try adding a second line to your test string like `"TEST\nT"` and switching between left and right alignment modes. But `SCNText` adapts to fit the coordinate system of its node, so alignment alone won't necessarily make the text fit into your scene the way you want it to.

You can tweak how a node's content fits into its parent space using the node's `pivot` property. Set it to a translation transform (`SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation`) based on the [bounding box](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNBoundingVolume_Protocol/index.html) of your text and you can change the layout however you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested "TEST\nT", but it is also not right aligned. Are you also using swift? What Device?

Comment: Ah, I was testing in an OS X playground. When I test in iOS simulator the right alignment fails. Looks like this might be an iOS-specific bug -- [probably a good idea to report it.](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I just reported it.

Comment: I could center the text by adapting the position of the textNode based on the maximum x of the bounding box.`textNode.getBoundingBoxMin(v1, max: v2)`

Comment: That won't center-align multiple lines within the text, but if you don't need to you're in good shape. A better way to achieve the same effect might be by setting `pivot` to a translation transform — that way you can keep setting `position` relative to the scene instead of relative to the text.

Comment: I can confirm as well that alignmentMode seems broken on iOS as well. It would be nice if this bug was reported inhttp://openradar.appspot.com as well. As it stands now there is no easy way to center multi line text on iOS. I can also confirm that on the Mac, changing the alignmentMode to center does not save you from having to adjust the pivot if you want to rotate along the center axis of the text. So it is a multi pass operation to properly align the text, maybe SceneKit does not do by default for performance reasons.