# Center multi-line SCNtext on macOS SceneKit

Tags: macos, scenekit

This code, on macOS Catalina

```
    scnView.scene = SCNScene()
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    let root = scnView.scene!.rootNode
    let txt = SCNText(string: "This\nis\ncentered", extrusionDepth: 0)
    txt.font = NSFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 35)
    txt.string = NSAttributedString(string: "This\nis\ncentered", attributes: [.foregroundColor : NSColor.black])
    txt.flatness = 0.1
    txt.containerFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 800, height: 200))
    txt.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.right.rawValue
    txt.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.black
    let txtNode = SCNNode(geometry: txt)
    root.addChildNode(txtNode)
```

Produces this output

[image]

Which does not center the lines within the container rectangle.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652946/scntext-alignment-not-working-in-ios) and a few others, and it seems around 2015 this didn't work on iOS, but did work on macOS.

One thing that has changed since 2015 is that the string constant is no longer `kCAAlignmentCenter`but `CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center.rawValue`. I tried `right` and `justified`, which are also ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's the use of `NSAttributedString` that breaks the alignment. Removing the following line works as a workaround.

```swift
txt.string = NSAttributedString(string: "This\nis\ncentered", attributes: [.foregroundColor : NSColor.black])
```

Note that in any case SceneKit will use the `SCNMaterial` of the geometry to shade the object and won't take `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor` into account.

Comment: Thanks - didn't exactly solve my problem as I need to use attributed strings for fonts and formatting. But it got me on the track to solving it. Thought I had tried it, but turns out you can set the paragraph style of the attributed string to align to center.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use an attributed string, it looks like `alignmentMode` is disabled so it can rely on the attributed string's paragraph style. Here's the extension I'm using to quickly center an attributed string.

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func centered() -> NSAttributedString {
        let ps = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        ps.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        let newString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        newString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: ps, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: newString.length))
        return newString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me where "text" is your SCNText object

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

text.string = NSAttributedString(string: textString, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle])
```